# how to load property file in to spring boot project with annotations?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have written queries in property file. I want to read the property file in to one class with annotations in spring boot. How can i read it? And is there any better approach for writing queries in spring boot project?

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate fields in your components by `@Value("${property.name}")`

Else, you can use `Properties` Object in `java.util` package.

For example, i have a mode property, which values are dev or prod, i can use it in my beans as follow :

```
@Value("${mode:dev}")
private String mode;
```

The other approach is by using :

```
Properties pro = new Properties();
pro.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add your properties in application.properties file, you can read them inside the spring boot classes like:

```
    @Service
    public class TwitterService {
        private final String consumerKey;
        private final String consumerKeySecret;

        @Autowired
        public TwitterService(@Value("${spring.social.twitter.appId}") String consumerKey, @Value("${spring.social.twitter.appSecret}") String consumerKeySecret) {
            this.consumerKey = consumerKey;
            this.consumerKeySecret = consumerKeySecret;
        } ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @PropertySource to read the properties from a file and then pass them to a bean.  If you have a file called "queries.properties" that has a property like:

```
query1: select 1 from foo
```

Then your config might look like:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:queries.properties")
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

 @Bean
 public DbBean dbBean(@Value("${queries.query1}") String query) {
     return new DbBean(query);
 }
```

}